# Redirect all pages from old domain to new specific URL without trailing slash content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got an old domain, let's say oldomain.com where I need to redirect all traffic to a specific URL, newdomain.com/path

While redirects from oldomain.com go perfectly, anything with content after the trailing slash will be copied over in the newdomain url structure causing 404's.

For example visiting: oldomain.com/somepage will result in newdomain.com/pathsomepage

What I'm looking for are some rewrite rules that will redirect any and all traffic from oldomain.com to newdomain.com/path without changing the specific "newdomain.com/path" URL.

I'm currently using the rules bellow which leads to the result above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://newdomain.com/path [P]
```

PS: the redirect is going to a Magento store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reverse-proxy in your directives (the P flag in the rewrite), but since you are describing a redirect... In the old virtualhost you just need to add a simple Redirect directive like this:

```
Redirect / https://newdomain.example.com/
```

This will Redirect all requests no matter how they are made to the new domain. Example GET /something will be redirected to https://newdomain.example.com/something

If you want the target to be a fixed destination like https://newdomain.example.com/path no matter what, use RedirectMatch instead:

```
RedirectMatch ^ https://newdomain.example.com/path
```

Comment: He Ezra, thanks for pitching in. 
being redirected to: /something is exactly what I want to prevent.

for example: if you enter oldomain.com/crazy-url-whatnot I still want to to go to newdomain.com/path and not to newdomain.com/crazy-url-whatnot or newdomain.com/path/crazy-url-whatnot

does that make sense?

Comment: let me fix the answer then :)

Comment: That worked perfectly, I had been searching over 2 hours for that one.
Thanks a ton!